# Read Old Transaction in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I wish I could read the payload of a transaction and be able to extract information. I created a new entry in the ledger by invoking my chaincode's "createPerson" method

```
+ peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --waitForEvent --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n agrifood -c '{"Args":["createPerson","ADMIN0","GIACOMO","BAIAMONTE","06/04/1992"]}' --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
+ res=0
+ set +x
2020-02-04 16:11:07.796 UTC [chaincodeCmd] ClientWait -> INFO 001 txid [2a46c341d130e02df9b8c874cc7c91623c09b83d92d5058d73e04ec29dcc4ccb] committed with status (VALID) at peer0.org1.example.com:7051
2020-02-04 16:11:07.796 UTC [chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> INFO 002 Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200
```

From the cli I invoke the following command

```
peer chaincode query -C "mychannel" -n qscc -c '{"Args":["GetTransactionByID", "mychannel", "2a46c341d130e02df9b8c874cc7c91623c09b83d92d5058d73e04ec29dcc4ccb"]}'
```

And I get the following output

```
�
�
�
�
��������"   mychannel*@2a46c341d130e02df9b8c874cc7c91623c09b83d92d5058d73e04ec29dcc4ccb:

agrifood�
�
Org1MSP�-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
sy��
�&\K��^�ZCA!��
�
�
�
Org1MSP�-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
sy��
�&\K��^�ZCA!��  
J
H
F
agrifood�6

createPerson
ADMIN0
GIACOMO
    BAIAMONTE

06/04/1992�
�
 ~��VM<o.
�S�B���j�@���   �
��
agrifood�


ADMIN0



LASTPERSON�

LASTPERSON�0�^
PERSON0�S{"issuer":"ADMIN0","name":"GIACOMO","surname":"BAIAMONTE","birthdate":"06/04/1992"}
lscc

agrifoo�agrifood�0.1�
�
Org1MSP�-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
G0E!��{��n n����u{���DFr� 4�ڨ &Y�f��'��ti�m:��9$��ܦr���S笕G0E!ۖ%��m�+!�l�k����A��O���cO/* $�w�a=B�����
                      ��;�+I
                            u=N]��=D��
```

It seems that an incorrect encoding is used, the environment variable "LANG" of the cli is "en_US.UTF-8".
I believe that if the encoding was correct I could be able to parse some information such as the name of the method invoked by that transaction. Is it normal for the output to look like this? Are there other ways to read information from a transaction? Thanks in advance